# Fill null rows with last non-null value in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R that contains an unusual format of data. I want to convert this to a regular format. Below is an example of the input -

```
Brand | Product | Store | Sales
A                         35
        Prod1             10
                  Store1  2
                  Store2  3
                  Store3  5
        Prod2             25
                  Store1  10
                  Store2  15
```

Basically, the file contains data at the store level, and then it's aggregated in "outer" rows at the product and brand level as well.

The output I'm looking for is -

```
Brand | Product | Store | Sales
A       Prod1     Store1  2
A       Prod1     Store2  3
A       Prod1     Store3  5
A       Prod2     Store1  10
A       Prod2     Store2  15
```

How can I transform this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::fill`: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/fill.html
and finally filter out empty rows in Store.

```
df %>% 
   fill(Brand) %>%
   fill(Product) %>%
   filter(drop_na(Store))
```